# Compare child property with parent property?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class Master
{
    public int? TotalAmount;
    public ICollection<Detail> Details;
}

public class Detail
{
    public int Amount;
}
```

I'm trying to create a rule so that the details collection's total amount is equal to the master's total amount property.

I'm trying the following rule but I can't access the master's property:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Details)
    .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Amount) == x.TotalAmount)
    .When(x => x.Details != null)
    .When(x => x.TotalAmount.HasValue);
```

What is the correct way to implement this kind of rule?

Comment: As a side note. Why validate things which can simply be calculated just inplace? This kind of validation will require calculation anyways, but the whole thing gets more complex.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser Classes and property names are examples for the sake of this question.

Comment: Either way, the point he's making is that you're causing a situation where you are having to enforce synchronization between two tables data, essentially duplicating functionality that otherwise could exist in only the detail objects, regardless of the specific example you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use another overload of Must, like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Details)
    .Must((master, details, ctx) => master.TotalAmount == details.Sum(r => r.Amount))            
    .When(x => x.Details != null)
    .When(x => x.TotalAmount.HasValue);
```

However note that, as already pointed in comments, you should not use validation for consistency checks. You just have one piece of data (sum of details amount). So why just not do like this:

```
public class Master {
    public int? TotalAmount
    {
        get
        {
            if (Details == null)
                return null;
            return Details.Sum(c => c.Amount);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Detail> Details;
}
```

Comment: I know I could do this and I was going to go this way, however I didn't want to add such a property to the model class to avoid adding such logic in a POCO class.

Comment: I cannot imagne much cases it would be reasonable to do that, but anyway you know your situation better than me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to achieve this type of validation is to use a custom validator method like the following:

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Master>
{
    public Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(master => master)
            .Must(CalculateSumCorrectly)
            .When(master => master.Details != null)
            .When(master => master.TotalAmount.HasValue);
    }

    private bool CalculateSumCorrectly(Master arg)
    {
        return arg.TotalAmount == arg.Details.Sum(detail => detail.Amount);
    }
}
```

Notice that the rule here is being described as applying to the entire master object; `RuleFor(master => master)`. This is the trick that allows you to access both properties.